# How to set params for file-exists-behavior for AWS CodeDeploy on Bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

[Atlassian Bitbucket Support for AWS CodeDeploy was announced](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/announcing-atlassian-bitbucket-support-for-aws-codedeploy/) long time ago in 2015.

[AWS CodeDeploy User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-user.pdf)
is explaining what exactly is executed on the instance to generate codeDeploy deployment.

my question is how do we set a param for

```
--file-exists-behavior
```

I wan it to be `OVERWRITE`, but it feels like it is `DISALLOW` by default.

I know it is possible, because this is how it worked on elstic-beanstalk (Amazon Linux) on another project, however now I'm using Ubuntu and I don't have access to previous settings. It cannot be possible only for Amazon Linux, right?

Comment: --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE

Comment: yes, if it was not Bitbucket generating the executing command but me, I'd add this param jus like you suggested. But am I in control of it, if yes - how can I control it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but I ran into this issue myself, so here's a fix for those still struggling with bitbucket and aws codedeploy:

Go to the file: `codedeploy_deploy.py` and change the call to the create_deployment and add the option `fileExistsBehavior='OVERWRITE'`. It should end up like this:

```
response = client.create_deployment(
    applicationName=str(os.getenv('APPLICATION_NAME')),
    deploymentGroupName=str(os.getenv('DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME')),
    revision={
        'revisionType': 'S3',
        's3Location': {
            'bucket': os.getenv('S3_BUCKET'),
            'key': BUCKET_KEY,
            'bundleType': 'zip'
        }
    },
    deploymentConfigName=str(os.getenv('DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG')),
    description='New deployment from BitBucket',
    ignoreApplicationStopFailures=True,
    fileExistsBehavior='OVERWRITE'
)
```

I had to upgrade boto3 from 1.3.0 to the current one (1.9.201)

Comment: Than you, but I realised it was a bad practice doing it. Because it does not delete files that should not be there. Thus, instead of overwriting, I delete everything and copy only a new set of files. It is longer, but it covers the deletion issue.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev I hadn't thought of that... You just saved me a lot of future trouble <3